# How to resolve undefined symbols for architecture i386

Tags: ios, xcode, linker, ld

I've recently downloaded some source from a git repository into Xcode 6.1.1. However, I'm getting "missing required architecture i386" for a library that's include with the app (and existing on my filesystem). 
Here's the error:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/myname/Documents/mycomp-mycompapp-ios/mycomp/libs/zbar_iOS7_Fix/libzbar.a, missing required architecture i386 in file /Users/myname/Documents/mycomp-mycompapp-ios/mycomp/libs/zbar_iOS7_Fix/libzbar.a (3 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ZBarReaderView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MyViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've gone through some similar postings, but I'm having trouble working out what the solution is - is it related to build settings, do I import another library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's looks like Xcode doesn't link your library in the "Build phases". These is the steps to do in order to fix it:

TargetSettings -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources -> add your ZBarReaderView.m class (and others if necessary) -> Build and Run

Comment: Thanks - but I'm still getting the same error message.

Comment: Did you clean before rebuild?

Comment: The problem seems to be that the .h files are included with the code, but the .m files aren't.

Comment: Actually, it turned out that it had to be run on the device itself - maybe has something to do with the simulator not having a camera.